# La pagina se pone en blanco al usar 'use client' en Nextjs 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next

Estoy intentando hacer un menu amburguesa que se muestra al tener menos de 480px, el menu posee una estructura simple, un logo, un boton y las pestañas. Al dar click al boton el menu se muestra y al hacerle click de nuevo el menu se esconde, esto se logra mediante hooks y funciones, en teoria la logica esta bien y deberia funciona, pero no lo hace, al usar hook useState, me pide que ponga el  'use client' y al hacer esto, la pagina se pone en blanco. Este componente esta hecho en una carpeta a parte llamada components, fuera del src/app.

El codigo funciona de la siguiente forma, tenemos un hook:
`const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);`

con un estado inicial que es false, el estado 'menu' entonces es false, y este estado esta puesto en la etiqueta nav:`<nav className={`header_nav ${menu ? "isActive" : ""}`}>`

Por si solo este hook no hace nada solo oculta el nav, ya que esta en false, para ponerlo en true necesitamos de la funcion:

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
        setMenu(!menu);
      };
```

Esta funcion la llamamos mediante un evento onclick, este boton es el menu amburguesa:

```
<button className="header_boton" onClick={toggleMenu}>
```

Los que usan next, saben que el 'use client' se usa cuando hacemos uso de hooks, por lo que se debe poner un 'use client' al principio. Pero al hacer esto la pagina se pone en blanco. Puedo asegurar con toda certeza que el problema esta entre el 'use client', el hook y la funcion.

Ustedes mismo pueden comprobarlo, eliminando el: 'use client', todo los relacionado hook, la funcion y la llamada de la funcion. y sustituyendo el en la linea `<nav className={`header_nav ${menu ? "isActive" : ""}`}>` el menu, por un true o false, en este caso funciona, pero no puedo automatizar el proceso, necesito ayuda, ¿Como reparo esto?

```
'use client'
    import { useState } from "react"; 

    import Image from "next/image";
    import logoMax from "../assets/images/background/logoMax.png";
    import burguer from "../assets/images/background/burguer.png";
    import "../styles/globals.css";

    export default function NavBar() {
      /*Este hook sirve para activar o no el classname 'active'*/
      const [menu, setMenu] = useState(false);
    

      /*Esta funcion sirve para el boton*/
      const toggleMenu = () => {
        setMenu(!menu);
      }; 
    
      return (
        <header className="header">
          <div className="header_imageYboton">
            /* Este es el logo*/
            <a href={"#Inicio"} className="header_logo">
              <Image
                src={logoMax}
                alt="icon-logo"
                className="header_image"
                width={70}
                height={50}
              />
            </a>

             /* Este es el boton*/
            <button className="header_boton" onClick={toggleMenu}>
              <Image src={burguer} alt="menu-amburguesa" width={40} height={40} />
            </button>
          </div>
          

          /* Esta es la lista que se muestra o se esconde*/
          <nav className={`header_nav ${menu ? "isActive" : ""}`}>
            <ul className="header_ul">
              <li className="header_li">
                <a href={"#Inicio"} className="header_link">
                  Inicio
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
      );
    }
```

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón por la cual tienes `components` fuera de `src/app`? mueve esa carpeta dentro de `app`, actualiza los imports y avisanos de los resultados.

Comment: Hola g.4, gracias por responder, el error era esta linea: import React, { useState } from "react"; yo solo habia llamado al useState pero tambien debi haber llamado a React.

Comment: Esta interesante, cuando era un server component no se quejaba de la falta de `React`, pero va al cliente y lo solicita...